# Exclude json object in list that does not contain a vale

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, json-query

How do you remove json objects that do not contain a specific value?  In the json below how do you keep
objects block that contains "11.22.33.0/24"?

How can this be achieved with jinja or Ansible filtering?

**json content**

```
my_data:
  description: "for load balancer access"
  group_is: "sg-1234"
  group_name: "MY GroupName"
  ip_permissions:
    - from: 80
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 80
    - from: null
      ip_protocol: "-1"
      ip_ranges:
        - cidr_ip: "11.22.33.0/24"
          description: "MY site"
      to_port: null
    - from: 22
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 22
    - from: 3306
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 3306
    - from: 3000
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges:
        - cidr_ip: "11.22.33.0/24"
          description: "MY site"
      to_port: 3000
    - from: 443
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 443
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace the images with text. Cut&Paste would make the testing easier.

Comment: For reason when I had the text in. Stackoverflow flagged it with to much code

Comment: This is strange. I was able to type the data in.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How do you keep objects block that contains "11.22.33.0/24"?"*

A: Given the JSON content in the variable `my_data`, use `json_query` to create the list of objects block `my_ip_permissions` and `combine` the result. For example, the tasks below do the job

```
   - set_fact:
        my_ip_permissions: "{{ my_data.ip_permissions|json_query(my_query) }}"
      vars:
        my_query: "[?ip_ranges[?cidr_ip == '11.22.33.0/24']]"
    - set_fact:
        my_data: "{{ my_data|combine({'ip_permissions': my_ip_permissions}) }}"
```

---

With the variable my_data

```
my_data:
  description: "for load balancer access"
  group_is: "sg-1234"
  group_name: "MY GroupName"
  ip_permissions:
    - from: 80
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 80
    - from: null
      ip_protocol: "-1"
      ip_ranges:
        - cidr_ip: "11.22.33.0/24"
          description: "MY site"
      to_port: null
    - from: 22
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 22
    - from: 3306
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 3306
    - from: 3000
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges:
        - cidr_ip: "11.22.33.0/24"
          description: "MY site"
      to_port: 3000
    - from: 443
      ip_protocol: "tcp"
      ip_ranges: []
      to_port: 443
```

the output was

```
    "my_data": {
        "description": "for load balancer access", 
        "group_is": "sg-1234", 
        "group_name": "MY GroupName", 
        "ip_permissions": [
            {
                "from": null, 
                "ip_protocol": "-1", 
                "ip_ranges": [
                    {
                        "cidr_ip": "11.22.33.0/24", 
                        "description": "MY site"
                    }
                ], 
                "to_port": null
            }, 
            {
                "from": 3000, 
                "ip_protocol": "tcp", 
                "ip_ranges": [
                    {
                        "cidr_ip": "11.22.33.0/24", 
                        "description": "MY site"
                    }
                ], 
                "to_port": 3000
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting this output `code`:{
        "description": "for load balancer access",
        "group_id": "sg-12345",
        "group_name": "my-LoadBalancer",
        "ip_permissions": ""
    }`code`
How can I add the from_port, ip_protocol and to_port?

Comment: I don't know. I've typed your data and the result fits the requirement.

Comment: I updated my Ansible to the current version.  thanks! @Vladimir Bokta